# Use an 18 W, 120 VAC shaded-pole motor on a 240 VAC circuit

Tags: voltage, motor

I need a simple way of using an 120 VAC shaded-pole motor on a 240 VAC circuit. The motor draws 18 W, so it has 800 Ω impedance.

Can I simply put two 400 Ω, 50 W resistors in series with the motor to reduce the voltage to 120 VAC? If I understand correctly, I should drop 120 V across the motor, and 120 V across the two series resistors.

Am I missing something, or would it be this easy?

Comment: Get a 240 V motor and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: "The motor draws 18 W" not unless the installation is very peculiar, and includes something to spin up to some defined speed before the power is turned on.  What leads you to believe the motor consumes 18W?  Is that the nameplate rating, your measurement of current, or what?

Comment: The product description and the label on the motor both state 18W at 120 volts.   The motor is part of a wall-mounted heater, so the motor is not easily changed out.

Comment: Transformer and done. 18 VA is a tiny transformer.  If you can't find anything else, get a 240V to 24V thermostat transformer and a 120V to 24V thermostat transformer, both common-as-dirt furnace parts in 40 VA capacity, and connect them nose to tail.

Answer (score 1):

Motor current will change due to loading, which means that the voltage dropped across the resistors will change (I * R).  A step-down transformer for this power level is the correct choice and will not cost significantly more than the resistors (< $20 from a reputable source - *not* Amazon).  I would take a look to see if the motor has terminals that can be re-configured for 120V operation.

Comment: In my experience with little shaded pole motors they aren't designed to change voltage.  I live in North America, so they're all designed for 120VAC.  Having said that -- I'd be surprised that for any given motor, there isn't a close equivalent available in a catalog for 220VAC even in the US, but especially in a 220VAC country.

Comment: The motor runs a small fan, so once it starts, the load doesn't change.    I've been poking around trying to find a small step down transformer, I could use some suggests as to reputable suppliers.